# How do I install nagios?

Tags: software-installation

I keep hearing about [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/), a really powerful tool for monitoring servers. How do I install it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First of all, I'm assuming that you're doing this on a stock, brand-spanking new install of 12.04. Nothing special happening here.

Install nagios:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nagios3
```

It will go through, and ask you about what mail server you want to use:

[image]

Pick one based upon your needs.

[image]

It will then ask you about the domain name you want to have email sent from. Again, fill that out based upon your needs.

It will ask you what password you want to use - put in a secure password. This is for the admin account `nagiosadmin`.

[image]

And then you'll need to verify your password.

Once the install is all done, you can head over to `localhost/nagios3` (or whatever the IP address/domain name of the server you installed it on is) and you'll be asked to enter your password:

[image]

Once you've done that, you're in!

[image]

<sub>Little ugly, huh?</sub>

Nagios automatically adds in the 'localhost' to the config, and does load, current users, disk space, http and ssh checks.

[image]

Now there is one more thing we need to do before nagios is all ready - we need to have it accept external commands so we can acknowledge problems, add comments, etc.

To do that, we need to edit a few files. Start by opening `/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg` with the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg
```

Search for `check_external_commands`, and turn the `check_external_commands=0` into `check_external_commands=1`.

Now, restart apache by running

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Not done yet! We need to edit `/etc/group`. There should be a line like this in there:

```
nagios:x:114
```

Change it to

```
nagios:x:114:www-data
```

Save and close this file.

Now, we need to edit the `/var/lib/nagios3/rw` files permission with:

```
sudo chmod g+x /var/lib/nagios3/rw
```

And then (because of how permissions work) we need to edit the permissions of the directory above that with:

```
sudo chmod g+x /var/lib/nagios3
```

Now, restart nagios with:

```
sudo service nagios3 restart
```

If you use Apache as your web server, restart that also:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And you should be good to go! Happy monitoring!

To have alerts emailed to you, [see this question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/155248/6005).

Comment: This install method does not work on a AMD64 server: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.gandi.net/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bind9/bind9-host_9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb 404 Not Found
[Skip] I guess one need to compile from source... JPM

Comment: @jpm: interesting. Nagios doesn't require BIND.

Comment: perhaps `sudo usermod -a -G nagios www-data` is less error prone than editing `/etc/group` directly.

Comment: Agree with @shabbychef. Also though, everything after __"...there is one more thing we need to do before nagios is all ready"__ seems to not be necessary for standard functionality of Nagios. Why does one need to accept commands from a file by default, when the file `/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg` actually states `Nagios will *not* check for external commands, just to be on the cautious side`?

Comment: Because otherwise, many (if not most) nagios plugins and checks won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This howto on Linode.com is very detailed, and works with Nagios 3:

http://library.linode.com/server-monitoring/nagios/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin

and here's a nice summary of how to monitor a website using Nagios 3:

http://ostatic.com/blog/monitoring-web-services-with-nagios

and here is another good example of configuring both Nagios and Apache, and configuring escalations:

http://bobcares.com/blog/?p=67

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: i completely agree, but I don't have time to copy it all in here nicely ;-) If someone wishes, they can copy it in here as another answer. The hard part was finding these concise summaries of how to do it! Thanks!

Comment: @bradparks for monitoring, our nagios tag here is becoming a fairly complete resource - I have documentation on how to email. For monitoring web services, that's more serverfault material, and almost considered common or basic knowledge.

Comment: Hey! I think the question was quite general, and I think the majority of people would want to a) install nagios and b) setup/install a configuration for monitoring a website. So to me, I think this fits  within the general nature of this question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I recommend follow [Nagios official Quickstart guide](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/quickstart-ubuntu.html), which does not use **apt-get**, but download the source code, compile and then install.

This would ensure your Nagios is installed at /usr/local/nagios/

I find the advantage that Nagios installed at /usr/local/nagios/ when I try to install Nagios Service Check Acceptor, a add-on for Nagios.

Comment: -1 See [jrg](http://askubuntu.com/users/6005)'s [comment above](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145518/#comment326036_261109)