# How can I make Nagios sends its Notifications and alerts to Known emails like gmail, hotmail etc

Tags: notification, postfix, gmail, nagios3

I started recently learning about Nagios Server version 4.2.3, i installed it on a VMware and configured it to monitor a host and ssh service on that host, the host also on a VMware.
The question is, how can i make nagios sends its notifications to gmail email?
i follow the steps on the link below, but i got nothing.
[How can I have nagios alerts emailed to my gmail?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155248/how-can-i-have-nagios-alerts-emailed-to-my-gmail)

Notice1: I installed both postfix and heirloom-mailx, i don't configure them, so if they need any configuration please guide me through.

I really looking for your help gues.

Comment: Do you have static IP address?  The link you mentioned makes sense for dynamic IP address or for nets with blocked outgoing SMTP connections (as **outgoing** spam prevention).

Comment: Hi @AndrzejA.Filip
Thanks for your reply, actually i don't have a static IP address.
How do i check if my network blocked outgoing SMTP?
if does, how can i fix this in order to make nagios send emails to gmail account?
thanks in advance