# Where Are My Config Files In Nagios?

Tags: nagios3

I installed Nagios by following the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145518/how-do-i-install-nagios).

I wonder where will be config file are. I can see plenty of places files resides. For example I can see `nagios.cfg` in two places :

```
/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

and

```
/etc/nagios3
```

which I need to configure? And also there are two `commands.cfg` file :

```
/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects
```

and here :

```
/etc/nagios3/commands.cfg
```

I'm very much confused in configuring the files I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nagios configuration file resides in `/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg`

It is the base for all Nagios configuration files.

For detailed info please see [Here](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/toc.html)

Comment: What do you mean by `base for all`? For all versions of nagios installed? Then what for: `/etc/nagios3` ?

Comment: Till date I'm adding my `.cfg` file into `/etc/nagios3/conf.d` directory. And I can see my changes in web interface. Am I doing it correct? Can you clearly put up the difference between those directories?

Comment: The info is a lot.  I've updated the answer above with a link of information about Nagios.

Comment: @Mitch: The locations seem to have changed over the years. I recently installed nagios on 18.04 LTS. The main configuration file is at /etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg, and there is no such directory as /usr/local/nagios.