# CPU utilization mail alert for any running services

Tags: scripts, monitoring

I need to get e-mail alert if %CPU is above 95% for any current running services. Can any body help me for this script?

Answer (score 1):

You best answer is likely going to be Nagios. It's host monitoring software that does just this (among other things). It's a bit complicated to get installed but [this guide should help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145518/how-do-i-install-nagios).