# Can't enter password in nagios3 installation wizard

Tags: software-installation, nagios3

I am trying to install nagios 3 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 using [How do I install nagios?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145518/how-do-i-install-nagios)

I have entered `sudo apt-get install -y nagios3` followed by my password.
I then get the dialog in the link below:

[image]

The text below "Nagios web administration password:" looks strange almost as if I have entered it (which I haven't).

The text in the screenshot also looks different to that in the guide I am following.

I don't appear to be able to enter a password into the dialog and the only keys that the dialog will respond to are the arrow keys and the enter key. I haven't experienced any other text entry problems in the terminal.

I am using kitty as my terminal emulator. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try another terminal, say `xterm`.

In any case, the password that is being asked here is for basic authentication via your (usually Apache) webserver. It is saved using [`htpasswd`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html) files, so you can set a blank password now and always set it later. Install `apache2-utils`, and then run:

```
sudo htpasswd /etc/nagios3/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin
```

(You can also run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nagios3-cgi`, to go through the configuration steps again.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, there is some useful information there.  Unfortunately the backspace key doesn't delete any thing and if I leave the passwords blank it says the passwords don't match.