# How to change the username and password for nagios site access on config files

Tags: server, password, nagios3

This explains how to configure username and password during initial configuration:

[How do I install nagios?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145518/how-do-i-install-nagios/145519#145519?newreg=bdc450618a20485bbbfbf16116276197)

How can I change that using config files on server if I've lost the username and password?

Answer (score 5):

```
$ find / -name nagios*.conf

###/etc/httpd/conf.d/nagios.conf

$ cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/nagios.conf | grep AuthUserFile 
###AuthUserFile /etc/nagios/passwd
$ sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nagios/passwd nagiosadmin
```

Comment: Thank you for the 'how to find your passwd' file... that really helped me.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nagios3/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin
```

Enter a strong password when prompted.

Note the -c replaces all existing passwords. To simply update an existing one (without affecting others):

```
sudo htpasswd /etc/nagios3/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin
```

Comment: Note the  -c _replaces_ all existing passwords. To simply update an existing one (_without_ affecting others)

`sudo htpasswd  /etc/nagios3/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin`

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

username - nagiosadmin
password - nagios

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
htpasswd /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin
```

It will ask for new password.